# Разные типы пользователей в Django

Tags: django, users

Мне нужно создать три разных типа пользователей на сайте, суть которых заключается в разных данных, которые должен заполнять пользователь в своем профиле. Грубо говоря, если это физ лицо, то он пишет адрес, ФИО и т.д. Если юрлицо, то реквизиты, счета и т.д. Все эти поля необходимые и должны валидироваться. При этом пользователь может менять свой тип. Однако права никак не меняются. 
Можно было бы создать одну таблицу и настроить видимость полей формы в зависимости от типа пользователя, но при этом будет проблема с валидацией. Возможно было бы лучше создать одну связывающую таблицу с наследоваием от User и настроить ее связь с тремя дополнительными классами пользователей. Но сделать эту связку выбора?

Answer (score 1):

От User ни в коем случае нельзя наследоваться. 
В вашем случае оптимально сделать модель Profile с OneToOneField к User
и там прописать логику.

Comment: спасибо. как сделать выбор типа формы, которую должен заполнить полльзователь? этот ключевой момент я не понимаю( можно как-то прикрутить выбор формы к Field.choices?

Comment: @martell Может, Вам стоит передавать тип по POST запросу и ветвить представление в зависимости от выбора?

Comment: создать профиль с общими полями и определить метод пост, в котором задать дополнительные/разные поля. я правильно понял?